How do I make my screen go black on lock after a timeout but keep HDMI on?
I'm currently running Ubuntu 24.04.1 x86_64. Sometime in the recent past, I updated and that has changed the way the screen locks.
In the past, when the screen lock kicked in, it would leave my monitor on but with a black screen. That's the behavior I want. Today, when the screen locks, HDMI is disabled and my KVM switch changes to another video channel. I'd rather have it stay on the current channel.
I tried the solution in How to lock without turning the screen (monitor) off? but running gnome-screensaver-command -l also turns off HDMI, and my KVM switches to the next machine with an active video source.
I also tried Ubuntu 16.04 lock screen without dimming/turning off but apparently Wayland breaks xscreensaver.
Is there a way to have the screen dim after some interval, the machine lock after some larger interval, but HDMI to stay active (so moving the mouse/typing changes the black screen to a lock screen)?

First thing to do is get your OS fully upgraded. A fully upgraded OS would be 22.04.4  sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade

Hmm... after  sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade and a reboot I see 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded, yet /proc/version_signature still says Ubuntu 6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3-generic 6.8.12 for LTS.

Oh fun. /proc/version_signature says I'm 22.04.3 but lsb_release -a says I'm 22.04.4 LTS, as does /etc/os-release.

Good idea to fix the info in the question.

Now upgraded to 24.04.1 LTS. Edited the question.

I had no luck on Wayland. I ended up switching back to X which lets me use xscreensaver.
